# Samsung S4 won't charge from socket

Tags: battery, charging

I am looking for help before sending my phone to maintenance service. 
All of sudden my phone stopped charging from a socket. The phone is charging (bolt showing, charging screen showing etc) but actually it won't charge at all. We tried different chargers (got originals from Samsung and HTC) and different wall sockets. Nothing helped. I was able to charge it from USB in a car and USB from laptop (of course instead of 2-3 hours to fully charge it took over 5 hours but it works.) Also charged it from powerbank.
I purchased new battery but still got the same problem so the glitch is not in battery or socket charger ... any ideas?

Comment: Did you change charging cables? Guessing you did but checking. Next you can back up data and do a factory reset and see if problem persists

Comment: Well it was one thing I googled, however not very thrilled to do that, but will try.

Comment: If factory reset or **safe mode** ( if your device has that option) shows same behaviour, IMO it requires hardware check

Comment: What is safe mode exactly?

Comment: See https://support.sprint.com/support/article/FAQs-related-to-Safe-Mode-on-your-Samsung-Galaxy-S4/WFAQ_542_GKB81861-dvc7300002prd.  It basically rules out third party or installed apps causing trouble

Comment: You can update your question with findings of safe mode behaviour instead of reporting in comments.

Comment: +1: I had a device with the same behaviour, and I never found out the reason.